# To convert Sql with case clause to Hql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I need to convert this sql query to hql.

Sql query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t2.Ammount * CASE WHEN t2.idAccountDeb = c.id AND t2.idAccountDeb<>t2.idAccountCred  THEN 1 
           WHEN t2.idAccountCred AND t2.idAccountDeb<>t2.idAccountCred  THEN (-1) ELSE (0)  END),0)
```

Hql query that did not work:

```
(select COALESCE(SUM(t2.Ammount * CASE WHEN t2.AccountDeb = c AND t2.AccountDeb<>t2.AccountCred  THEN 1 
             WHEN t2.AccountCred AND t2.AccountDeb<>t2.AccountCred  THEN (-1) ELSE (0)  END),0)
```

AST Hibernate error:

```
ERROR: <AST>: 2: 24: unexpected AST node:.
```

Comment: Thank you for the report on the status of your current development efforts. Did you have a question you wanted to ask? (BTW, there are syntax problems in your example SQL query; there is no way that SQL query doesn't produce an error.)

Comment: sorry typing error. I'll remake. My english is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the MySQL:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN t2.idAccountDeb t2.valor * = c.id AND t2.idAccountDeb <> 1
                         THEN t2.idAccountCred 
                         WHEN AND t2.idAccountCred t2.idAccountDeb <> t2.idAccountCred
                         THEN (-1)
                         ELSE (0)
                 END), 0)
```

This code is not syntactically correct.  `*=` is not a MySQL operator (the list is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html)).  The second `when` misformed.  I might guess that the intended logic is:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t2.idAccountDeb = t2.valor AND t2.idAccountDeb <> 1
                THEN t2.idAccountCred 
                WHEN  t2.idAccountDeb <> t2.idAccountCred
                THEN -1
                ELSE 0
           END)
```

Or something like this.  This logic should work in both MySQL and HQL.

EDIT:

Something like this should work in both databases:

```
SELECT SUM(t2.Ammount * (CASE WHEN t2.idAccountDeb = c.id AND t2.idAccountDeb = t2.idAccountCred
                              THEN 1 
                              WHEN t2.idAccountDeb = c.id AND t2.idAccountDeb <> t2.idAccountCred  
                              THEN -1
                              ELSE 0 
                         END)
           )
```

Comment: In addition to those syntax problems, it seems like that SQL query  would still produce an error, without a reference to a `t2` rowsource.

Comment: remade. sorry typing error. I'll remake. My english is bad

Comment: good, very good. I did the same question here in Brazil 2 hours ago and nothing. Time's money.

Comment: I made ​​some adaptation in the code, but solved my problem with case clause.`SELECT SUM(t2.Ammount * (CASE WHEN t2.idAccountDeb = c.id AND t2.idAccountDeb <> t2.idAccountCred
                              THEN 1 
                              WHEN t2.idAccountCred = c.id AND t2.idAccountDeb <> t2.idAccountCred  
                              THEN -1
                              ELSE 0 
                         END)
           )`